# Recover history from foolish git-svn merge

Tags: git, git-svn

the players:

master:  the svn branch (actual, not local trackign)
mybranch:  a local branch

My mistake:

```
[master] git svn rebase
[master] git merge mybranch
[master] git svn dcommit
```

I did this *twice*.

Is there a way I can remedy all this?  I was thinking something like:

1. git checkout --hard [commit before the merging]
2. git dcommit # that to the svn?
3. git rebase mybranch
4. git dcommit

But this doesn't seem to work.

(I know I should a. working from a local tracking branch  and b. have rebased rather than merged)

I'm in the frantic / willing to send beer to respondents stage :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since rewriting history on the SVN side is hard, why not try dcommit a new commit which effectively cancel what you have previously dcommitted twice?

```
git log # grab the commit hash you want to revert
git revert <commit hash>
git svn dcommit
```

[`git revert`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-revert.html)

> Given one existing commit, revert the change the patch introduces, and record a new commit that records it.

Comment: Not really what i'm looking for, but I have my problem solved-ish.  I'm not worried about rewriting svn history... just trying to *additionally* get the history I lost into svn.  Ultimately i was unsuccessful in doing so, despite using revert, and a bunch of other tools.

Comment: @Gregg, sorry to read that. You could document what you have ultimately done in an answer of your own in this page.